# How to fix Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist (Error) when i echo out the pagination link to the html?

Tags: php, laravel

This is the first time that i encounter this problem on my pagination link, I really don't understand why this error shown to my blade when i retrieve the pagination link. so to understand well I will show to you the sample controller and html page that I already created on my project. The main goal here is to paginate the list product that already inserted to the database table.

Laravel Version: 5.8

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

> Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\waps_project_app\resources\views\management\waps\product_history.blade.php)

**Html:**

```
<div style="margin-top:50px;">
<h3>Product History</h3>
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr style="font-size:12px;">
            <th>Category</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach($data as $product_data)
            <tr class="product_details" >
                <td class="item_code" style="font-size:12px;">{{$product_data->posting_category}}</td>
                <td class="item_name" style="font-size:12px;">{{$product_data->item_name}}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px;">{{$product_data->item_qty}}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px;">{{number_format($product_data->item_price,2)}}</td>
                <td style="font-size:12px;">{{$product_data->created_at}}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
    {{ $data->links() }}
</table>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function product_history() {

    $product_table = DB::table('product_basic_info')->get();

    return view('/management/waps/product_history',['data' =>$product_table]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are calling wrong method in your controller, function below in controller suppose to use paginate() function of laravel, only when you call that function, you would be able to use function links() to render pagination in your blade. You may take a look in laravel document [Laravel Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/pagination). I hope it would help.

```
public function product_history() {

    $product_table = DB::table('product_basic_info')->paginate();

    return view('/management/waps/product_history',['data' =>$product_table]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change like this

```
$product_table = DB::table('product_basic_info')->paginate(15);
```